# iOS Saving form data to multiple files

Tags: iphone, ios, file, save, overwrite

I'm working on an app that has a form in it. When the form is filled out and the user hits the 'Submit' button a file is saved with the Name of the person and the current date/time. Each time the form is filled out and submitted, (unfortunately) the file gets overwritten with the current file. My question is, how can I have the same form save as a different file each time it is filled out without overwriting the previous file?

Comment: I think we really need more information, like how your trying to save this "Form Information". Some code would help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an algorithm to append a number to any file with a conflicting name:

```
- (NSString *)getDocumentPath{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent://nameOfFile];

        //Check For Duplicate Objects
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
            int i = 0;
            //Duplicate Found, enter while loop to append number to it.
            while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
                //nil out string
                NSString *newString = nil;
                NSString *pathExtension = nil;
                //build string with new number
                newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",[[self.itemArray objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row] stringByDeletingPathExtension],i];
                pathExtension =[[self.itemArray objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row] pathExtension];
                //query again for duplicates
                if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[[[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:newString]stringByAppendingPathExtension:pathExtension]]) {
                    //success, break,write to file
                    return [[[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:newString]stringByAppendingPathExtension:pathExtension];
                    break;
                }
                //nope, increment int and try again
                i++;
            }
        }
    else return path;

}
```